# -fno-omit-frame-pointer equivalent compiler option for clang

Tags: clang, clang++, streamline

I want to use `DS-5 Streamline profiler` to profile my code. In the documentation its mentioned that to be able to see call stacks, we need to compile code with compiler option `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. This option is there in gcc.
Is there an equivalent option for clang also?

`-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is not working for me with clang.

I have also tried setting the compiler optimization level to 0, but still I am not getting call stacks in streamline.

Comment: Do you also use `-g` or `-ggdb` or similar?

Comment: On my target I run stripped shared libraries. But while analyzing captures, I provide unstripped so's that have the debugging symbols (compiled with -g)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like DS-5 is an ARM thing, so this might not be relevant, but I ran into a similar issue trying to get good stack traces out of a clang-compiled executable using Linux's [perf profiler](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html).

The problem ended up being that, on x86-64 Linux at least, Clang requires both `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` **and** `-mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer` in order to get the same behavior that gcc gives with only `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. See this LLVM bug: ["Need both -fno-omit-frame-pointer and -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer to get a fp on linux on a leaf function"](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9825)