# Why does this code generate much more assembly than equivalent C++/Clang?

Tags: optimization, rust, llvm-codegen

I wrote a simple C++ function in order to check compiler optimization:

```cpp
bool f1(bool a, bool b) {
    return !a || (a && b);
}
```

After that I checked the equivalent in Rust:

```
fn f1(a: bool, b: bool) -> bool {
    !a || (a && b)
}
```

I used [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/) to check the assembler output.

The result of the C++ code (compiled by clang with -O3 flag) is following:

```
f1(bool, bool):                                # @f1(bool, bool)
    xor     dil, 1
    or      dil, sil
    mov     eax, edi
    ret
```

And the result of Rust equivalent is much longer:

```
example::f1:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov al, sil
  mov cl, dil
  mov dl, cl
  xor dl, -1
  test dl, 1
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 3], al
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 4], cl
  jne .LBB0_1
  jmp .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 2], 1
  jmp .LBB0_4
.LBB0_2:
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 2], 0
  jmp .LBB0_4
.LBB0_3:
  mov al, byte ptr [rbp - 4]
  test al, 1
  jne .LBB0_7
  jmp .LBB0_6
.LBB0_4:
  mov al, byte ptr [rbp - 2]
  and al, 1
  movzx eax, al
  pop rbp
  ret
.LBB0_5:
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 1], 1
  jmp .LBB0_8
.LBB0_6:
  mov byte ptr [rbp - 1], 0
  jmp .LBB0_8
.LBB0_7:
  mov al, byte ptr [rbp - 3]
  test al, 1
  jne .LBB0_5
  jmp .LBB0_6
.LBB0_8:
  test byte ptr [rbp - 1], 1
  jne .LBB0_1
  jmp .LBB0_2
```

I also tried with `-O` option but the output is empty (deleted unused function).

I intentionally am NOT using any library in order to keep output clean. Please notice that both `clang` and `rustc` use LLVM as a backend. What explains this huge output difference? And if it is only disabled-optimize-switch problem, how can I see optimized output from `rustc`?

Comment: Did you compile with `-O` (in release mode)?

Comment: @Boiethios Yes I did, but it removes the whole code (as unused). Making function `pub extern` works :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Compiling with the compiler flag `-O` ([and with an added `pub`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563133/why-doesnt-the-godbolt-compiler-explorer-show-any-output-for-my-function-when-c)), I get this output ([Link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/NriTWc)):

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
xor     dil, 1
or      dil, sil
mov     eax, edi
pop     rbp
ret
```

A few things:

- **Why is it still longer than the C++ version?**

  The Rust version is exactly three instructions longer:

  ```
  push    rbp
  mov     rbp, rsp
  [...]
  pop     rbp
  ```

  These are instructions to manage the so called frame pointer or *base* pointer (`rbp`). This is mainly required to get nice stack traces. If you disable it for the C++ version via `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, [you get the same result](https://godbolt.org/g/gsh6Hs). Note that this uses `g++` instead of `clang++` since I [haven't found a comparable option for the clang compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864881/fno-omit-frame-pointer-equivalent-compiler-option-for-clang).
- **Why doesn't Rust omit frame pointer?**

  Actually, it does. But Godbolt adds an option to the compiler to preserve frame pointer. You can read more about why this is done [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11906). If you compile your code locally with `rustc -O --crate-type=lib foo.rs --emit asm -C "llvm-args=-x86-asm-syntax=intel"`, you get this output:

  ```
  f1:
      xor dil, 1
      or  dil, sil
      mov eax, edi
      ret
  ```

  Which is *exactly* the output of your C++ version.

  You can "undo" what Godbolt does by [passing `-C debuginfo=0` to the compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/L7oVpK).
- **Why `-O` instead of `--release`?**

  Godbolt uses `rustc` directly instead of `cargo`. The `--release` flag is a flag for `cargo`. To enable optimizations on `rustc`, you need to pass `-O` or `-C opt-level=3` (or any other level between 0 and 3).

Comment: Please stress the fact that you added `pub` to the function signature. Godbolt produces empty output without this.

Comment: @jaskmar There is [a dedicated question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563133/why-doesnt-the-godbolt-compiler-explorer-show-any-output-for-my-function-when-c).

Comment: I mean the info for future readers of this post to prevent confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Compiling with `-C opt-level=3` in godbolt gives:

```
example::f1:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  xor dil, 1
  or dil, sil
  mov eax, edi
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Which looks comparable to the C++ version. See [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45562380/1245027) for more explanation.

Note: I had to make the function `pub extern` to stop the compiler optimising it to nothing, as it is unused.

Comment: Oh so `-C` is how you pass `opt-level`. I tried `-O`, but that just removed `f1` completely.

Comment: Still looks like there's a pointless stack frame created

Comment: Simple `-O` instead of `opt-level` also works but only if you make function `pub extern` :)

Answer (score 4):

To get the same asm code, you need to disable debug info - this will remove the frame pointers pushes.

`-C opt-level=3 -C debuginfo=0` (https://godbolt.org/g/vdhB2f)

Answer (score 2):

**It doesn't** (the actual difference is much smaller than shown in the question). I'm surprised nobody checked the C++ output:

[godbolt C++ x64 clang 4.0, no compiler options](https://godbolt.org/g/FcgocA)

[godbolt Rust 1.18, no compiler options](https://godbolt.org/g/sUY2qM)