# Why doesn't the Godbolt compiler explorer show any output for my function when compiled in release mode?

Tags: rust

I want to use https://rust.godbolt.org to see the assembly output of this function:

```
fn add(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
    a + b
}
```

Pasting this on the website works fine, but shows a lot of assembly. This is not unsurprising, given that `rustc` compiles my code in debug mode by default. When I compile in release mode [by passing `-O` to the compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/KMgj1y), there is no output at all!

What am I doing wrong? Why does the Rust compiler remove everything in release mode?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Godbolt compiles your Rust code as a library crate by passing `--crate-type=lib` to the compiler. And code from a library is only useful if it's public. So in your case, your `add()` function is private and is removed from the compiler completely. The solution is rather simple:

**Make your function public by adding `pub` to it.** Now the compiler won't remove the function, since it is part of the public interface of your library.

Comment: Sometimes adding `pub` to a function is not enough, especially for small wrapper functions. You should add `#[inline(never)]` to the top-level functions for which you want to see the disassembly.